# MONACA - Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings

Tags: angularjs, facebook, oauth, monaca

I am using http://monaca.mobi to develop an mobile application to log on facebook , I created the app in developer.facebook.com .
To open the facebook login interface, use the appinbrowser and load the login page , the message "Given URL is not whitelisted in OAuth Client Settings ... " , my application is not in a domain on the Internet , is locally in a cell , how to proceed in this case? I've tried to use http://localhost to the field of application and also for REDIRECT_URL , but it worked .

Has anyone done this login using Monaca / angularjs ?

Comment: Is it an Android or iOS app? Then you have to use the native SDKs

Comment: Monica is a hybrid ide, like PhoneGap, to dont need to use natives plataforms.